# I cannot paginate with the ListModelMixin class an action decorator

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good night I can not paginate with the ListModelMixin class an action decorator, the question is that I page but I show on each page the total number of objects that are going to be displayed, that is, if I have 27 records, the 27 is shown on each page.

Page 1

[image]

Page 2

[image]

```
 class PostPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20

 class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class = PostPageNumberPagination

    def get_response_data(self,paginated_queryset):
        data =[ {
                'id_interface': interface.id_interface,
                'id_EquipoOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen_id,
                'EquipoOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.nombre,
                'LocalidadOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.localidad,
                'CategoriaOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.categoria,
                'id_PuertoOrigen': interface.id_PuertoOrigen_id,
                'PuertoOrigen': interface.id_PuertoOrigen.nombre,
                'estatus': interface.estatus,
                'etiqueta_prtg': interface.etiqueta_prtg,
                'grupo': interface.grupo,
                'if_index': interface.if_index,
                'bw': interface.bw,
                'bw_al': interface.bw_al,
                'id_prtg': interface.id_prtg,
                'ospf': interface.ospf,
                'description': interface.description,
                'id_EquipoDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino_id,
                'EquipoDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.nombre,
                'LocalidadDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.localidad,
                'CategoriaDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.categoria,
                'id_PuertoDestino': interface.id_PuertoDestino_id,
                'PuertoDestino': interface.id_PuertoDestino.nombre,
                'ultima_actualizacion': interface.ultima_actualizacion,
            } for interface in self.queryset]
        return data

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path='registros-data-table', url_name='registros_data_table')

    # List ModelViewSet

    def registros_data_table(self, request):
        queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            data = self.get_response_data(page)
            return self.get_paginated_response(data)

        data = self.get_response_data(queryset)
        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Where are you using ListModelMixin? can you put the entired code where you're using it? or can you explain details of what are you trying to do?

I think what you are currently doing is complex without reason. According to [Django rest framework pagination docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/), it is simple to make pagination.

In your api.py file you need:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

And in each ViewSet, just add:

```
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

Comment: I am using the ModelViewSets list, which is due to the action, and the page as you are telling me does not work in action methods, since I tried it and it did not page me, it is necessary to use the ListModelMixin, which until now is the only one method that I know, but I get the error they see in the images.